# How to remove back end of a list in python?

Tags: python, list, range

So for part of class, I have an given input from a `txt` file. Basically, an input string I can be given is something like

```
listy = ["Miko's Lounge", '41.2', '56.7', '99th Ave, NY', '3', '4', '5', '2']
```

What I need to do with this input is remove the address, and put the numbers at the end of the list into their own list within the list, like so.

```
["Miko's Lounge", '41.2', '56.7', ['3', '4', '5', '2'] ]
```

I know I can remove the address using `listy.pop(3)`. But the numbers at the end of the string can vary! These represent star ratings, and some places have more star ratings than others. Is there I can remove all of the indexes from a certian point in the list and on, like the function `slice()`, kind of?

What I've been trying is to use a for loop using the `range` function, but it doesn't seem to work properly (or how I expect it to).

```
listy = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']


for i in range( 2 , len(listy)-1 ):
    listy.pop(i)

print listy
```

What I'm getting as an output:

```
['1', '2', '4']
```

When I'm trying to get something more along the lines of:

```
['1', '2']
```

Why is the random `'4'` in there? I don't understand this range thing! I miss java with the simple for loops -_-

Comment: The `homework` tag has been [deprecated](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated?cb=1). As it stands, your question is helpful without it, so I'm removing it.

Comment: Your method of removing the items within a loop is a problem because the indices keep changing.  That's why you get the strange result.  One way to get around that is to remove the items starting at the back, but python has a much simpler way to remove a section of a list.

Comment: Your second example could be handled by just doing `del listy[2:]` to delete everything from index 2 (third element) onwards.

Comment: If you are looping over indices in Python, you are doing something wrong.

Answer (score 12):

You can use [list slicing](http://techearth.net/python/index.php5?title=Python%3aBasics%3aSlices) to do this easily:

```
>>> listy[:3]+[listy[4:]]
["Miko's Lounge", '41.2', '56.7', ['3', '4', '5', '2']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try that:

```
listy = ["Miko's Lounge", '41.2', '56.7', '99th Ave, NY', '3', '4', '5', '2']
l = listy[:3]
l.append(listy[4:])
l
```

Gives you:

```
["Miko's Lounge", '41.2', '56.7', ['3', '4', '5', '2']]
```

Comment: I would just do `l = listy[:3] + [listy[4:]]` like the other answer; the `append` is superfluous.

Comment: @nneonneo ``append()`` is just as valid. That said, this answer is essentially just a repeat of mine.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably have already read the docs for List: 
http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html

However, I'm not seeing the syntax you're looking for, either.

I think what you want is the two-part index syntax that replaces the common container method 'slice'

the way python addresses a sublist is with

```
myListInstance[start:end] //<-- note the colon
```

More information:

http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#the-del-statement

Comment: [@lattyware](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12683599/401735), below has the better answer; I took to long trying to remember the details.

Answer (score -1):

First, your list `listy` has five elements.
When you delete index 2 element there are 4 left and len(listy) returns 4 hence listy[3] is deleted. Hence you have `[1,2,4]`.
I hope you have understood how the result came.
Modify

```
for i in range(3):
    listy.pop(len(listy)-1)
print listy
```